# Why Does Jquery Mask Plugin Change Result When Using QR Code Reader

Tags: javascript, jquery, qr-code, barcode-scanner

I'm using Jquery Mask plugin to mask a number called RA which looks like 123.456.789-0, it works but when I use one of those QR/Barcode readers it simply changes the value to 124.568.907-3, see the code below in which there's two input fields, one with mask and one without, the one without works with the correct number.
Also the reader apparently sends Enter at the end that's why I setup a form to catch that.

```js
(function($) {
  const raMaskBehavior = (val) => {
      return val.replace(/\D/g, '').length === 10 ? '000.000.000-0' : '00.000.000-09';
    },
    raMaskOptions = {
      placeholder: '00.000.000-0',
      onKeyPress: (val, e, field, options) => field.mask(raMaskBehavior(val), options)
    };
  const maskRa = () => $('.number').mask(raMaskBehavior, raMaskOptions);

  setInterval(() => {
    maskRa();
  }, 1000);
})(jQuery);

$().ready(() => {
  $('#form').submit(e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert($('#ra').val());
  });
  $('#form2').submit(e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert($('#ra2').val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.16/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>

<form id="form" action="#">
  <input type="text" class="number" id="ra" required />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
<form id="form2" action="#">
  <input type="text" id="ra2" required />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: QR code or Barcode? There is a difference :) Because bar-codes have different formats and standards... that should be preset when using decoding libraries like (QuaggaJs) . So please mention the used decoding library and the targeted format if it's a barcode

Comment: @Bilel it's QR code but I'm not using a library, I'm scanning it with an actual plug-and-play scanner, and it gives the right result on the field that is not masked and on notepad.